# How to create with comma separated with single qoutes list from array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, implode

This is my question that i have this type of string

```
04/19/2017, 04/20/2017, 04/26/2017, 04/28/2017
```

i want to output as like below output

```
'04/19/2017','04/20/2017','04/26/2017','04/28/2017'
```

Comment: Look into [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) and [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

Comment: You should paste your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using  explode and implode

`$string = "04/19/2017, 04/20/2017, 04/26/2017, 04/28/2017";
$string = "'".str_replace(", ","','",$string)."'";`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
// dates in a string
$data = '04/19/2017, 04/20/2017, 04/26/2017, 04/28/2017';

// break them apart into array elements where the , is
$dates = explode(',', $data);


/* You then have array of dates you can use/display how you want, ie:: */
foreach($dates as $date){
    echo $date. '<br/ >';
}

/* OR select single date */
echo $dates[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "04/19/2017, 04/20/2017, 04/26/2017, 04/28/2017";
$array = explode(", ", $string);
$string = "'".implode("','", $array)."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

For your specific example, you can use:

```
$result = preg_replace('%([\d/]+)%sim', '"\1"', $string);
```

---

Output:

```
"04/19/2017", "04/20/2017", "04/26/2017", "04/28/2017"
```

---

Regex Explanation:

```
([\d/]+)

Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «([\d/]+)»
   Match a single character present in the list below «[\d/]+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
      A “digit” (any decimal number in any Unicode script) «\d»
      The literal character “/” «/»

"\1"

Insert the character “"” literally «"»
Insert the text that was last matched by capturing group number 1 «\1»
Insert the character “"” literally «"»
```

---

[Demo](http://ideone.com/frnyk3)

Comment: Can you add an explanation of your regex?